# What does "No matching signature for operator = ...etc." mean?

Tags: sql

I am trying to run this query in SQL and I keep getting this message:

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, STRUCT<start_station_id INT64, number_of_rides INT64>. Supported
> signature: ANY = ANY at [18:54]

Line [18:54] refers to the INNER JOIN **ON** statement [station_id = start_station_id]

-- Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
station_id,
name,
number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station

 FROM 
      (
        SELECT
          start_station_id, 
            COUNT (*) number_of_rides
        FROM
         bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
        GROUP BY
          start_station_id
      )
      AS start_station_id
  INNER JOIN
  bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations ON station_id = start_station_id
  ORDER BY
  number_of_rides
```

Comment: Columns station_id and start_station_id data type(s)?

Comment: try `CAST(start_station_id AS STRING) AS start_station_id`  in your subquery.

Comment: Having start_station_id as table alias is quite confusing as it's already a column name.

Comment: And potentially that is what is causing the problem. `STRUCT<start_station_id INT64, number_of_rides INT64>` is the columns of your derived table so it seems to be trying to do an equality against the whole row rather than just the `start_station_id` column. What happens if you change `AS start_station_id` to `AS number_of_rides_by_start_station`? Maybe `ON station_id = start_station_id` would also need to be changed to `ON station_id = number_of_rides_by_start_station.start_station_id`

Comment: Thank you everyone, your suggestions worked. I CAST the ON statement as STRING, as follows: ON CAST (station_id AS STRING) = CAST (start_station_id AS STRING)        I also changed the Alias column name in my subquery to: num_of_rides_by_start_station

Comment: If you need to do cast to JOIN, it often indicates inconsistent column data types.

Answer (score 0):

Had trouble with the learning video instructions in course as well. Solution to change data type from string to integer and run query: `safe_cast(station_id AS int64) = start_station_id`